# EMR job stuck at 67% without any response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, hadoop, emr, beautifulsoup

I have written a simple script to analyze commoncrawl data. Following is the snippet of my mapper.

```
src_code = record.payload.read().replace('\r', '').split('\n\n')[1]
soup = BeautifulSoup(src_code.strip(), "lxml")
[x.extract() for x in soup.findAll(['script', 'style'])]
txt = soup.get_text().encode('utf8')
try:
    isReliable, textBytesFound, details = cld2.detect(txt)
except:
    txt = ''.join(x for x in txt if x in string.printable)  # Handle invalid utf-8 chars
    details = cle.detect_txt_lang(txt)
```

I have to analyze warc.gz files (as I have to get some header info also). I have tested my mapper on local cluster with same hadoop version as on EMR. It takes 40 minutes for 5 files( I have slow Internet). But when I run this job on EMR, It stuck at 67% for about 41 minutes (findall I have to kill it). 
Where is the problem? Above script read content (html code expected) and then call a method to find text language if possible.
Is it a parser problem ? or language method problem (this method is cld2 library method)

Just little more details. I have used m1.medium on EMR (for testing). I have given just one input i.e. one warc.gz file only.
Following is the log of EMR job

```
2017-01-14 05:00:21,840 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Job job_1484542573756_0001 running in uber mode : false
2017-01-14 05:00:21,843 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 0% reduce 0%
2017-01-14 05:00:47,163 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 67% reduce 0%
```

Comment: Are you sure all content fits in the memory?

Comment: content is streaming using warc file

Comment: 67% mapper or reducer? also, add logging

Comment: I have updated question. My reducer phase is simple cat only.